Очистка list от значений прошлых итераций цикла
Решаю задачу, в которой необходимо найти сумму максимального и минимального делителей первых пяти чисел больше 800000, есть list, который хранит все делители числа, проблема заключается в том, что при попытке очистить list от значений в конце итерации цикла, случается инвалидация итераторов,
вопрос: как очищать list в конце итерации, чтобы это не приводило к вышеуказанной проблеме.
UPD.Забыл добавить некоторые детали условия, делители являются натуральными, кроме единицы и самого числа по условию, нужно найти сумму делителей, которые оканчиваются на 4 и вывести число, делителями, которого они являются и саму сумму делителей
Прилагаю свой код ниже:
int main()
{
    list<int>sum;
    for (int i = 800000; i < 800100; i++)
    {




        for (size_t del = 2; del <= i/2; del++)
        {
            if (i % del == 0)
            {
                sum.emplace_back(del);
            }
        }
        if ((*min_element(sum.begin(), sum.end()) + *max_element(sum.begin(), sum.end())) % 10 == 4)
        {
            cout << i << endl << *min_element(sum.begin(), sum.end()) + *max_element(sum.begin(), sum.end()) << endl;

        }


    }
}


А зачем и как вы его вообще чистите? И у вас что-то код, скажем так, не совсем тот, что в условии требуется...

Кстати, а зачем вы вообще используете список? он там ни к чему. Второе — а что делать, если число простое? Ведь, я так понимаю, 1 и само число как делители не рассматриваются?  Оно, конечно, 800011 в диапазон "первых пяти чисел" не попадает, но как быть, если его расширят? :)

@Harry, включение единицы и самого числа в "делители" делает задачу неинтересной. Предположу что составители сознательно избегают простых из диапазона.

ТС, подумайте над вопросом: как связаны между собой минимальный и максимальный делители?

Забыл добавить некоторые детали условия, делители являются натуральными, кроме единицы и самого числа по условию, нужно найти сумму делителей, которые оканчиваются на 4 и вывести число, делителями, которых они являются и саму сумму делителей

@Harry, Я использую список для хранения всех делителей и дальнейшего извлечения минимального и максимального

@StanislavVolodarskiy , вы натолкнули меня на верную мысль(произведение минимального и максимального делителей равны самому числу), благодарю
